# How to check if class attribute defined in StackFrame?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I need to skip `System.Diagnostics.StackFrame` routes of my `class` in my exeption middleware.

Currently I can check in exception `StackFrame` if my methods have `[StackTraceHidden]` attribute.

For example this is how my class looks now (attribute needs to mark every method):

```
public class ValidString
{
    private string _value;

    [StackTraceHidden]
    public ValidString(string value)
    {
        Validate(value);
        _value = value;
    }

    [StackTraceHidden]
    private void Validate(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));  
    }

    [StackTraceHidden]
    public static implicit operator ValidString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new ValidString(value);
    }
}
```

And how I skip marked methods in `StackFrame`:

```
    foreach(StackFrame stackFrame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        if (!stackFrame.GetMethod().IsDefined(typeof(StackTraceHiddenAttribute), true))
            return stackFrame;
```

It doesn't feel right to mark every method of classes I need to skip with these attributes.
I want mark my `class` with `[StackTraceHidden]` attribute to skip all `StackFrame`'s that are registered at this `class`.

This is how I want it to be (attribute only marks class):

```
[StackTraceHidden]
public class ValidString
{
    private string _value;

    public ValidString(string value)
    {
        Validate(value);
        _value = value;
    }

    private void Validate(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));
    }

    public static implicit operator ValidString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return new ValidString(value);
    }
}
```

And that's how I imagine to skip whole class from `StackFrame`:

```
    foreach(StackFrame stackFrame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        if (!stackFrame.GetClass().IsDefined(typeof(StackTraceHiddenAttribute), true))
            return stackFrame;
```

**In short:** How to do something like this?

```
bool markedWithSomeAttribute = stackTrace.GetFrame(i).GetClass().IsDefined(typeof(SomeAttribute), true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/907789/how-to-check-if-class-attribute-defined-in-stackfr.html

**The solution:**

```
bool marked = stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(StackTraceHiddenAttribute));
```